# Are projective sets from descriptive set theory projective objects in Set category?

Tags: category-theory, descriptive-set-theory

There are [projective sets](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Projective_hierarchy) in descriptive set theory. [For them](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Axiom_of_projective_determinacy), the axiom of determinacy is not contradicting the axiom of choice.

Given the axiom of choice, every set is a projective object. But in a world without AC, is any projective set a projective object in the sense of category theory? Or did those terms happen to use the same word and there is any counterexample?

Answer (score 1):

It's just a coincidence. Being projective in the descriptive set theory sense is a property of a subset of a Polish space (i.e., how it sits inside the ambient space matters). But projectivity in the category theory sense is preserved by isomorphisms. So if $X$ and $Y$ have the same cardinality, $X$ is a projective object iff $Y$ is, regardless of any ambient space.

Moreover, in the category of sets, every set is projective. (Note that the axiom of choice is required to prove this.)

Comment: But "being Polich space" is saved by `Set` isomorphism as well. So being analytic or being projective set should be isomorphism invariant as well.

Comment: "axiom of choice is required" Yes, that is the kind of point of the question, it does not make sense with AC. Will update description to clarify that.

Comment: @uhbif19 Being Polish is *not* preserved by set isomorphism. The property "there exists a Polish topology on $X$" is preserved by set isomorphism, but every set of cardinality continuum satisfies this property...

Comment: Okay. Still, Borel isomorphism exists between any uncountable Polish space. Why would not this be enough?

Comment: @uhbif19 Enough for what? Take a non-Polish subspace $X$ of $\mathbb{R}$ of cardinality $2^{\aleph_0}$. Then $X$ and $\mathbb{R}$ are isomorphic in the category of sets, but $\mathbb{R}$ is Polish, while $X$ is not. Similarly for $X$ a non-projective subset of $\mathbb{R}$ of cardinality $2^{\aleph_0}$. The category of sets is just too course to reflect any of the structure that's relevant for descriptive set theory.